# Can't delete branch with a space character inside its name

Tags: git, bitbucket

One of my team mates, managed to put a space character(at least it's rendered as a space) inside a branch name, so the branch names looks like ' feature/XX-NNN-adasd-asd-asd-asd-ads'. That space at the start of the branch name doesn't allow me to reference it from a terminal or delete it.

We are using BitBucket as our VCS server

Things that i already tried:

- git branch -d " feature/XX-NNN-adasd-asd-asd-asd-ads"
- git branch -d \ feature/XX-NNN-adasd-asd-asd-asd-ads

Comment: Have you tried `git branch -d " feature/XX-NNN-adasd-asd-asd-asd-ads"` (putting your branch name in quotes)?

Comment: Please show the command line that you are using.

Comment: `git branch -d \ feature/XX-NNN-adasd-asd-asd-asd-ads` Put a `\\` before the space.

Comment: Are you sure, there is a space character? The docs say, that you cannot use space in branch names (See: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html )

Comment: i don't know if it's really a space character or it's rendering it like a space, but that thing is there and it's really annoying. EX: if i check the url of the branch in bitbucket, that character is not enconded as anything and it should be enconded as %20.       https://xxxxxx.org/bitbucket/projects/SSP/repos/xxx/compare/commits?sourceBranch=refs%2Fheads%2F feature%2FSSP-xxxxxxxxx    the space it's just before "feature%2FSSP-xxxxxxxxx "

Comment: Sorry my las comment doesn't show the important fragment of the url. `sourceBranch=refs%2Fheads%2F feature%2FSSP-362` could you see the   space after `feature%2FSSP-362`? it should be a %20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following as a workaround:

```
git branch | grep "feature/XX-NNN-adasd-asd-asd-asd-ads" | xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: oh, that's very clever, i like it

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Intellij as my development IDE and it allowed me to delete the branch using it's CVS Tools.

Anyways, i don't really understand how my mate was able to do something like that, i'm gonna try to replicate the problem.

PD: Thanks for your comments and ideas.